# How to add fallback font for glyphs which doesn't exist on current font?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, fonts, firefox-addon

So, on Windows default font family files don't have flag emoij (e.g.  turns into  and ). You can add this emoij by defining @font-face.

How do you make that, the fallback family is the previous value? Or how to append it? Or how to do it in general (adding a character to the font-family)?

---

UPD: Ok, here is an example:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Country Flags';
  unicode-range: U+1F1E6-1F1FF;
  src: url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/country-flag-emoji-polyfill@0.1/dist/TwemojiCountryFlags.woff2') format('woff2');
}
*{
    font-family: Fantasy;
}
#f{
    font-family: 'Country Flags';
}
```

```html
<p>Windows </p>
<p id="f">Custom </p>
```

[image: example result on Windows]

Look. Setting `font-family: 'Country Flags';` overrides every previous `font-family`.

You can have a plagin to add CSS, like [Stylish](https://userstyles.org/).
It adds CSS file to page.

The overriding of previous `font-family` is a problem, because you break what page is trying to indicate. For example [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) use `ui-monospace` for editor and `-apple-system` for normal text.

Again, that's only an example. If there is no why of adding emoij by this kind of plugin, then I will need to make new, more complex, plugin. Do you understand me now?

Comment: `You can add this emoij by defining @font-face.` font-face sets the *font family* that CSS can use, as far as I'm aware this has nothing to do with if the font family selected has any particular flag glyph (character). I think you should look into [**font awesome**](https://fontawesome.com/search?q=USA%20flag&o=r) for a solution to your needs.

Comment: @Martin I updated the question. `this has nothing to do with if the font family selected has any particular character` look it has.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. If you need different elements to use different font-family then you need to establish this in your CSS rule set; use one font-family for one set of elements and another font-family for another set of elements. Yes CSS can only (I think) use one font-family at a time, however, a **font-family** can have more than one font -- for example `font-family: 'coountry-flags', 'other-font', default-font, aerial;` so if a glyph is not found on the primary font it (might?) appear on the reserve fonts called?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare two fonts in font-family property?

```css
body {
    font-family: a, b;
}
```

Take a look at the code snippet below, which uses Thai symbols and Thai font for them. But other symbols which are not Thai will use Arial. So in your case just use `font-family: Fantasy, "Country Flags";`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Charm&display=swap');

body {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: black;
}

.arial-charm {
  font-family: "Arial", "Charm";
}
.charm-arial {
  font-family: "Charm", "Arial";
}
.charm {
  font-family: "Charm";
}
.arial {
  font-family: "Arial";
}
```

```html
<span class="arial-charm">Arial + Charm: ฟอน! test</span>
<span class="charm-arial">Charm + Arial: ฟอน! test</span>
<span class="charm">Charm: ฟอน! test</span>
<span class="arial">Arial: ฟอน! test</span>

Default font: ฟอน! test
```

Comment: I repeat "`The overriding of previous font-family is a problem, because you break what page is trying to indicate. For example StackOverflow use ui-monospace for editor and -apple-system for normal text.`". I will propably do adicional plugin insted.

Comment: What do you mean by `because you break what page is trying to indicate`? Do you apply some semantic logic to your fonts or what?

Comment: No, it's not my page. I'm talking from browser plugin perspective. Normaly, if you want to change how sites looks, you can add small CSS file. Look on example I gave [Stylish](https://userstyles.org/categories/global). `You can have a plagin to add CSS, like Stylish. It adds CSS file to page.` Why people don't understand me :( ?

Comment: Don't know.. You can try to change your point of view from person who asks to person who is trying to give an answer. Then edit your question.